# Bing map AJAX Control V7 - How do I prevent the context menu showing up on right click?

Tags: api, bing-maps

I have added a Bing map to my webbpage, and also added a event handler for the "rightclick" event.

When I rightclick on the map, the event fires, and at the same time the browser context menu shows. How can I prevent the context menu from showing?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any Bing map specific way of turning it off, however, one can do like this in prototype to prevent the context menu from showing on the div element containing the map

```
// Create map
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {credentials: 'bing_map_api_key'});
// Prevent the context menu from showing on right click on the map div using prototype
$('map').observe("contextmenu", function(e){
  e.stop();
});
```

Comment: Tried this and got $("map").observe is not a function.  'map' is the name of my div containing the loaded map. Any help, I have included jquery 1.4.1?

Comment: The example above is assuming prototype. For jquery i suppose you would use bind or something similar to add an event handler to the context menu event.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is quite different between Bing Maps v6.3 and v7.0.  Version 6.3 Uses the Virtual Earth libraries, as 7.0 uses the Microsoft.Maps libraries.

In 7.0 you can add event handlers to the map and objects of the map like so:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'rightclick', rightclickHandler);
```

Here is a great link for migrating between 6.3 and 7.0 that I have bookmarked on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237870.aspx

As for disabling the context menu, you can set oncontextmenu to return false so that when you right click you do not get the context menu as well.  I'm sure there are beter ways to do this, but this is a quick and easy trick.

```
 <body onload="GetMap();" oncontextmenu="return false">
```